# Data scraping with python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, web.py

Hey I created a script to datascrape a specific website, the code is ok but i get a error when i try to excecute the code.

Tried cmd to excecute the file so i can get results but still a error.

NameError: name 'scrape' is not defined

> > > ''scrape.py''
> > > File "", line 1

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "sawadee.nl/groepsrondreizen/midden-en-zuid-amerika/costa-rica" 
response = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 
for row in soup.select(".departure-list__table tbody tr"): 
    date = row.select_one(".departure-list__date").text.strip() 
    group = row.select_one(".departure-list__group").text.strip() 
    print(f"Op {date} is de groepssamenstelling: {group}")
```

Comment: you need to share the code I guess..

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sawadee.nl/groepsrondreizen/midden-en-zuid-amerika/costa-rica/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select(".departure-list__table tbody tr"):
    date = row.select_one(".departure-list__date").text.strip()
    group = row.select_one(".departure-list__group").text.strip()
    print(f"Op {date} is de groepssamenstelling: {group}")

Answer (score 0):

How did you run the script?

If you run it from the terminal you have to run something like this:

```
python file_name.py
```

Comment: Yes i did run the script like that but i receive following message:
''  File "<stdin>", line 1''

Comment: You may be inside the python interpreter. So run `exit()` and then try again `python file_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run it from cmd / python because i used Pycharm to create the script. Outcome of the script is a list with the information that I need in a excel file or csv.

I ran the script as: python scrape.py
that failed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your same code, but a small change by adding the https in front of the url. I was getting `200` in the response but the in the `soup.select` its failing due to some html parsing. You may have to check that cos I don't see a departure-list in any of the html tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://sawadee.nl/groepsrondreizen/midden-en-zuid-amerika/costa-rica"
response = requests.get(url). ### getting 200 response here
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for row in soup.select(".departure-list__table tbody tr"):
    date = row.select_one(".departure-list__date").text.strip()
    group = row.select_one(".departure-list__group").text.strip()
    print(f"Op {date} is de groepssamenstelling: {group}")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use exactly the same code?

\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\scrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: This is the response I get now when I execute the code again

Comment: you have to install those packages first before using it.... instal using pip --> `pip3 install requests` if you dont have pip then you need to install it first... but please if this has answered your original question please upvote or mark it as an answer

Comment: I already installed the packages

Comment: do a pip list and see whether the packages show up

Comment: pip 23.1 from C:\Users\Robel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)